# How do i crawl a javascript and ajax based web page data using php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to create a simple crawler using php for crawling a specific content of vodafone website.

I want to crawl the content from https://shop.vodafone.in/shop/rechargeOnline.jsp?cid=mum . In that,

View All Recharge->Bonus Card 5->Detals.

After clicking "Details" button, pop up window will appear. I want to extract whole data in the pop up window.

I'm able to extract static content. but the data in the pop up is depending of javascript and ajax call.

Somebody help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: You don't. You can't crawl dynamic content with the static PHP. PHP doesn't have Javascript, PHP doesn't care in the slightest about Javascript. However, as the site's not loading for me, open your Network tab in your Developer Tools, and see if there's a request being made to somewhere when you click on the Details button.

Comment: try this link https://shop.vodafone.in/ in that, go to Prepaid->Recharge Now->View All Recharge->Bonus Card 5->Details->Pop Up Please help me..

Comment: @VaijuSajjan, mate, you're not understanding the issue here - PHP doesn't render JS - You need to directly read that page that the AJAX call is made to - See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't render JS, so you can't do what you are asking.

But, that page is making a request which you can directly read. It's making a request to: https://shop.vodafone.in/shop/ajax/viewRechargeDetails.jsp?id=sku4760065

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pav. can you just tell me how did you come to know that its making request to https://shop.vodafone.in/shop/ajax/viewRechargeDetails.jsp?id=sku4760065. so that I can access other pop up data and move forward. I'm new to PHP, please bear with me for asking you silly thing.

Comment: @VaijuSajjan, If you're using Firefox you can install FireBug - When activated, click on the 'Console' tab. It will show you all dynamic requests. If you're using Chrome, activate the developer toolbar and click 'Console'.